# Downloading file and saving it to download folder using kotlin in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-networking

I am trying to download an apk file from the web server and store it in the download folder. I am using fuel library

```
Fuel.download("https://mypath/app.apk").destination { 
    response, url -> val dir = File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).toString()) File(dir, "abcd.apk")    
}.progress {
    readBytes, totalBytes -> val progress = readBytes.toFloat() / totalBytes.toFloat()
    Log.d("log",progress.toString())
}.response {
    req, res, result -> Log.d("log","download completed ")    
    Log.d("log",Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).toString() + "/abcd.apk")
}
```

I am getting `bytesArray` in `response` but the file is not saving to download folder. I have `write_external_storage` on my `Manifest` file. Please let me know what am I missing?

Comment: what is `targetSdkVersion` of your app?

Comment: targetSdkVersion = 23 , maxSdkVersion = 23 , minSdkVersion = 10

Comment: then implement rumtime permission for external storage.

Comment: Thanks. Now its working :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned in comment that you are using `targetSdkVersion` as 23. Beginning with Android 6.0 (API level 23), if you set `targetSdkVersion` as 23 in your app you have to implement rumtime permission in your app.

To implement it please refer official documentation here [Requesting Permissions at Run Time](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
fun storeImage(link: String) : String {
    val policy: StrictMode.ThreadPolicy = StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build()
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy)
    val cw = ContextWrapper(applicationContext)
    val directory: File = cw.getDir("imageDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    val pictureFile = File(directory, "backgroundImage.gif")
    URL(link).openStream().use { input ->
        FileOutputStream(pictureFile).use { output ->
            input.copyTo(output)
            Log.e("DD GIF", "storeImage: FILE SAVED" )
            return "SAVED"
        }
    }
}
```

it is working for me.

Comment: it will create file for backgroundImage.gif and then URL content will be download into backgroundImage.gif which is basically in your imageDir local private storage